# Extract data from JavaScript already in the DOM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to find a way using tag manager to fire some Javascript to read the data  outputted in a JS function.

The functions are as follows:

```
<script>var ga = ga || [];
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {"id":"1031396","affiliation":"Purchases","revenue":"149.98","currency":"GBP","tax":0,"shipping":0,"city":"Example","region":"Example","country":"GB"});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {"id":"1031396","sku":"000004","name":"Example","category":"Product: item","price":"80.000000","currency":"GBP","quantity":"1.00"});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {"id":"1031396","sku":"000013","name":"Example","category":"Product: item","price":"49.980000","currency":"GBP","quantity":"1.00"});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {"id":"1031396","sku":"item_adult","name":"Example","category":"Product: items","price":"20.000000","currency":"GBP","quantity":"1.00"});
ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Essentially, I would like to get an array of all the SKUs in this data, in order to send this to another channel.

I don't have access to the source code, so essentially using the existing code is the only option.

I'm just stuck of ideas on what to try to extract this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know the analytics code does not let you read properties that have been set via the `ga()` function. So the only, extremely hacky and bad-for-performance solution I can think of would be to do a bit of scraping via Javascript.

In a custom HTML tag you would need to set up a function that inspects the script tags in your page. Since the script tag does not have an id you'd need to collect them all, then read their contents as a string, and look into the string for a pattern (basically [as in my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678960/find-a-specific-line-of-script-using-js-jquery-in-gtm/31681367?r=SearchResults#31681367), only you'd be looking for "var ga = ga || [];" or similar).

You'd probably then split the resulting string into lines (by newline separator). You'd iterate over the resulting array. For each line you'd apply a regular expression that extracts the bits between the curly brackets. You would then apply a JSON.parse to the matches, and you would be able to access the properties of each object (or if you are better with regex than me you could directly extract the sku value). You shove this into an array, and then (probably) push it to the datalayer in your custom tag, so you can use it in your tags.

While this works, it is an extremely ugly solution. Much better to talk to your boss or client and have this done properly. If you have to do stuff like this add a disclaimer that you can give no guarantees that this will work in the future (usually if you have done it, you own it, and maintaining horrible hacks for the rest of your life will really bog you down in the long run).