# Is it possible to overwrite existing javascript on my page using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Our page is refreshing because it is expecting to ask for user input each time the page loads. I just want to change the refresh time from 3000ms to 100ms.

I'm a business user :) I do not have access to developers and management of our site is by a 3rd party. I do have access to GTM. I want to find out if there is a way that I can block a javascript from running or modify a value in the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
       var getloc = Mage.Cookies.get('storeb');
       //var getloc = "2018-12-24 21:39:35";
        if (getloc == null || getloc == '') {
            setTimeout(function () {
                jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
                    items: {
                        src: '#storeselect-popup',
                        type: 'inline'
                    },
                    modal: true
                })
            }, 3000);
        }

        jQuery('.mfp-popup').click(function(){
            jQuery('#storeselect-popup .messages').css('display','block');   
        });
        var outputpickup = jQuery('.pickup select').val();
        var outputship = jQuery('.ship select').val();
        if( outputpickup > 0 || outputship > 0 ){
            jQuery('#storeselect-select').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        jQuery('#storeselect-popup ol li select').on('change', function() {
            if( this.value > 0){
                jQuery('#storeselect-select').removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else if(this.value == 0){
                jQuery('#storeselect-select').attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
        })
        jQuery('#delivery_zip').keyup(function(e){
            if(jQuery(this).val().length == 5){
                jQuery('#storeselect-select').removeAttr("disabled");
            }else {
                jQuery('#storeselect-select').attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I can't get around having the page refresh, but I want to make the page refresh happen really quickly, hence the 100ms.

Comment: So you can't simply change the `3000` to `100`, is that right? Are you able to insert *new* Javascript onto the page?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: no, not for your use case.

The answer to the title - "is it possible to overwrite Javascript" - is "yes". You can overwrite variables and functions, or you can even [access the content of script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678960/find-a-specific-line-of-script-using-js-jquery-in-gtm/31681367#31681367) and overwrite it with something else.

For your particular use case, not so much. jQuery does not provide a way to override the document.ready function. Also you cannot clear your timeout, since clearTimeout needs a reference to the timeout and in your example it's not assigned to a variable. You could iterate over your script tags, delete the script with the timeout, and implement the changed timeout in a custom HTML tag, but that requires a minimum of programming skills and is an absolutely horrible solution that will probably fail for any number of edge cases. No matter what you think now, paying a developer to change this is undoubtely the better solution.